Unity+Android tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
I have a mobile Android SDK that programatically creates and displays a WebView containing an HTML5 video. The native Android version works correctly, however when I integrate the SDK into a Unity project, the WebView displays but the video does not, and the console is spammed with the tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw warning. I have looked at similar threads on here and the Unity forums, but they either referenced a bugfix in Chromium v77/78 or had no solution. I'm out of ideas and wondering if anyone had any experience with this issue. I'm leaning towards it being something related to how Unity works/builds apks, since it works in the native implementation. Any help is appreciated.

Can you try doing android:handwareAccelerated="true" , within AndroidManifest.xml .

@BobSmith unfortunately that doesn't solve it, same behavior with that line added

have you tried increasing the heap size ?

@BobSmith I tried the heap size variable in gradleTemplate.properties which didn't fix the issue. Is there another way to change the heap size?

gradleTemplate is for android studio setting so  you increased the heap size of android studio rather than the app use this in android manifest .xml <application         android:name=".MyApplication"         android:largeHeap="true" more info here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

@BobSmith Ah I see. Adding the android:largeHeap key doesn't fix the issue either

@ Mine bomber consider reading this post https://github.com/kitylam9/unity-webview/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#android and use jar in your project to load url in webview.

@BobSmith It turns out you were right about using hardwareAccelerated="true", but just putting that in the manifest didn't work since Unity overrides the AndroidManifest.xml file and forces it to be false. Using this script I was able to get things working. If you want to add an answer I'll send you the bounty

@Minebomber as suggested in my first comment android:hardwareAccelerated="true" generally fixes this type of issue in first go. But here in unity it forcibly make it false again. So again you will get same error.
Based on the technique discussed in
https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-hardwareaccelerated-is-forced-false-in-all-activities.532786/ and https://github.com/Over17/UnityAndroidManifestCallback, Assets/Plugins/Editor/UnityWebViewPostprocessBuild.cs

Solution is that generate a jar of the android native code and import it in unity project and use it as binary file so that it doesn't gets changed.
How to build WebViewPlugin.jar
The following steps :

Clone project https://github.com/kitylam9/unity-webview/tree/master/plugins/Android

Open Terminal.app and perform the followings.


$ export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/bin:~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
$ cd unity-webview/plugins/Android
$ ./install.sh

You should find
unity-webview/build/Packager/Assets/Plugins/Android/WebViewPlugin.jar if successful.
Usage:
Web Player
The implementation utilizes IFRAME so please put both "an_unityplayer_page.html" and "a_page_loaded_in_webview.html" should be placed on the same domain for avoiding cross-domain requests.
Reference link

https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

https://github.com/kitylam9/unity-webview/

https://forum.unity.com/threads/game-doesnt-install-on-android-12-from-playstore.1222065/#post-7794402


